# How to join two table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select

I have two tables, USER_TABLE and USER_ADDRESSES as mentioned below

[image]

[image]

I want output like below

[image]

I have tried as below but getting duplicate rows because of "USER_TRAVELLED_CITY" column in USER_TABLE

[image]

Comment: Add distinct after select i.e. `select distinct usr.first_name...`

Comment: How many records in TABLE1 have a USERID of `1001`? Why would you expect your query to return any fewer records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in `user_table` isn't normalized, hence producing these duplicate rows.

My suggestion would be to fix the database design and normalize it. If this isn't an option, you could use `distinct` to remove the duplicates from your result. Also, not that implicit joins (having more than one table in the `from` clause) are an outdated practice, and you should probably use an explicit `join` clause:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT usr.first_name, usr.last_name, usr.user_id, usr_add.user_addrs
FROM   user_table usr
JOIN   user_address usr_add ON usr.user_id = usr_add.user_id
WHERE  usr.user_id = 1001
```